# Scaling a single Pen in Wonderware Intouch Historical Trends

Tags: wonderware

Wonderware Intouch tags have several dot fields associated for scaling tag values (.minraw, .maxraw, .mineu, .maxeu). But it appears that these are read only dot fields. 
I need to be able to change the mineu/maxeu at run time for a single pen [associated to a specific tag] without changing the entire trends .MinRange and .MaxRange.

Example Scenario: We have 4 pens displaying historical data on an Intouch Historical Trend. The scaling on three of the pens is great for this particular view of the data but pen 4's data moves up and down only slightly as compared to the other pens. If we zoom in (.MinRange / .MaxRange) on just that pen then all the other pens data is off the Trend. How does one dynamically change scaling on just one pen?

Comment: Why did this get voted down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using historian client embedded in InTouch. I'm also assuming you're plotting all 4 tags with 1 axis rather that 4 individual axes.

From Historian Client manual (v.10.6):

You can scale single tag or all of the tags in a trend up or down. If you scale a tag down, the range of values increases by one third. For example, if the scale is 10 to 70, it becomes 0 to 80. If you scale a tag up, the range of values decreases by one fourth. For example, if the scale is 0 to 80, it becomes 10 to 70.

To scale single tag up, do one of the following:

1. On the Chart menu, point to Scale Tag and then click Scale Up.
2. Click the Scale Tag Up toolbar button

To scale single tag down, do one of the following:

1. On the Chart menu, point to Scale Tag and then click Scale Down.
2. Click the Scale Tag Down button